# Client stub Vs Client socket & Server stub Vs Server socket

Tags: c, sockets, rpc

## Background

> Any client socket program(C) over TCP/IP looks like,
>
> ```
>  /* Socket creation */
>  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
>
>  /* Do nothing for dynamic address assignment to that client socket */
>
>  /* Identify the server, we use to send a request for connection */
>    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
>    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
>    servaddr.sin_port = htons(8000);
>    inet_pton(AF_INET, serv_ip, &servaddr.sin_addr);
>
>  /* Connect request to listening socket of server */ 
>    ret_val = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
>
>  /* 
>     *
>        Communication code
>        ================== 
>        Here comes the code for application layer protocol using read() & write() call that follow FTP, HTTP, SMTP specific rules.
>     *
>     */
> ```
>
> Any server socket program(C) over TCP/IP looks like,
>
> ```
>   /* Create listen socket */
>     listfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
>
>
>   /* Assign protocol family(AF_INET) & address to that socket */
>     bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
>     servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
>     servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
>     servaddr.sin_port = htons(8004);
>     retval = bind(listfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
>
>   /* Enable the communication on that socket */
>     listen(listfd, 5);
>
>   /* with a specific server model(iterative/threaded/multiprocess/..) accept 
>  client request */
>      connfd = accept(listfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);
>
>   /* 
>      *
>        Communication code
>        ==================
>        Here comes the code for application layer protocol using read() & write() call that follow FTP, HTTP, SMTP specific rules.
>      *
>      */
> ```

---

Early host-to-host protocols focussed on human-to-computer communications
Ex: Email 1971, FTP and interoperable Telnet: 1973

There was interest in app-to-app protocol - RFC 707 that describes the manner in which a networked procedure call to be done.

RPC is the transfer of a *data structure* from client side stub to server side stub via `libnsl.so.1`, in ansi C world(say). Data structure 
 could hold a message for add operation(say), as shown below,

```
 -------------
| proc: "add" |
 -------------
| int: val(i) |
 -------------
| int: val(j) |
 -------------
```

---

Typical flow of an RPC for a remote `add(i, j)` operation,

### [image]

Client & server can differ in data representations(Big endian & Little endian). The external data representation (`add_xdr.c`) is an data abstraction needed for machine independent communication.

---

1. Is RPC, a machine independent communication?
2. In RPC world, Does packet handling code between *client stub* & *server stub* behave similar to *client socket* & *server socket*? with the difference in communication code carrying a *data structure* that holds procedure information `add(i, j)`

Comment: RPC is a generic term that encompasses several things starting with Sun-RPC, if not before. In general RPC is a *remote* procedure *call,* encompassing transmission of possibly a large number of primitives or structs as parameters, the call itself, and the return of a primitive or struct as the return value. Not what you said above. And I'never seen an actual implementation of RFC 707.

Answer (score 1):

RPC is machine-independent, in that 32-bit and 64-bit systems can communicate, it's not as interoperable as pure sockets between different OSes, as the two sides have to agree on a lot more details.

RPC works over transports between endpoints, some of which are not even representible as sockets (local memory as an example).

You can read about RPC at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373935(v=vs.85).aspx

RPC code does look quite different from socket code in that RPCs in the calling code look like any other function, it is only in those (usually tool-generated) functions that the data is bundled for transport.

Comment: Does packet handling code between client and server stub look similar to client socket and server socket?