# What would happen in a RPC Model if the result is not unpacked at client stub?

Tags: database, rpc, message-passing

In a **Remote Procedure Call (RPC)**, when an instruction is passed from client to N*etwork Routine>LocalKernel*, the instruction is packed in *client stub*,then sent to *Network Kernel* from the *Local Client Kernel*. Then this instruction is sent to *Server stub* and then the *server routine* processes it and passes the result to *server stub*. This result is again packed with necessary paramenters and sent back to *Local Network Kernel of server* then to *Client Kernel*,a then to *Client routine*. But what will happen if this packed information is "not unpacked" by client stub and directly sent to *client routine*?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still looking for an answer,

A packed stub consists of data necessary for the client/server to identify results. The reason for the stub is to make sure 2 systems working in different OS/language can understand respective code.

This post covers an overview - [Client stub Vs Client socket & Server stub Vs Server socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030186/client-stub-vs-client-socket-server-stub-vs-server-socket)

So, without unpacking the stub, the data would be unreadable by the client routine.